# How to make a callback global so I can use it to other functions?

Tags: c++, dll, stdcall

I declared a function like this:

```
int __stdcall DoSomething(int &inputSize, int &outputSize, void(* __stdcall progress)(int) )
{
}
```

How can I make progress() callback a global variable to use it in other functions in the same DLL?
I am a newbie to C++.

Comment: Just use `progress` as parameter?

Comment: @deviantfan But this another function should declare progress argument the same way?  void(* __stdcall progress)(int) ?

Comment: @Tom Yes, it should.

Comment: Also consider using a `typedef` for the function pointer type. That makes things look nicer, especially when various functions take it as a parameter. (And makes things easier if you ever need to modify the callback's signature.)

Comment: @TheUndeadFish Typedef is great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function with a matching signature (i.e., `void (*)(int)`).

```
#include <iostream>

//void (      *      )(     int    ) - same signature as the function callback
  void progressHandler(int progress)
{
    std::cout << "received progress: " << progress << std::endl;
}

int DoSomething(int &inputSize, int &outputSize, void (*progress)(int))
{
    progress(100);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int inputSize = 3;
    int outputSize = 3;
    DoSomething(inputSize, outputSize, progressHandler);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
received progress: 100
```

---

Even though I removed it (because I used `g++`) you can keep the `__stdcall`.